# Technical Feasibility of Uploading File from URL

Tags: apex

I want to know whether the following is achievable in Salesforce.

If I pass a string containing URI of a file to an apex class, the file should be uploaded to Salesforce.

Comment: can you expand a bit on this ?

Comment: where is the URI of file located ?On salesforce or other external website ?

Comment: Hi Mohith...As of now we are thinking of using dedicated File Server for this purpose. Eg : \\SERVER_NAME\DIR\FILE.csv etc

Comment: do you mean the file will be on local server and not on internet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can download the content of file by using URL and create attachment out of it.

The only criteria is that you add that url in Remote site setting.

Here is code sample that shows how to do it. Its copied from [Here](http://www.sundoginteractive.com/sunblog/posts/saving-the-contents-of-an-image-or-file-url-and-saving-to-an-attachment-or)

```
Http h = new Http();
HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
string firstImageURL = 'http://www.myDomain.com/myImage.jpg';
//Replace any spaces with %20
firstImageURL = firstImageURL.replace(' ', '%20');
req.setEndpoint(firstImageURL);
req.setMethod('GET');
//If you want to get a PDF file the Content Type would be 'application/pdf'
req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'image/jpeg');
req.setCompressed(true);
req.setTimeout(60000);             
HttpResponse res = null;
res = h.send(req);
//These next three lines can show you the actual response for dealing with error situations
string responseValue = '';
responseValue = res.getBody();
system.debug('Response Body for File: ' + responseValue);
//This is the line that does the magic.  We can get the blob of our file.  This     getBodyAsBlob method was added in the Spring 2012 release and version 24 of the API.
blob image = res.getBodyAsBlob();

Attachment n = new Attachment();
//You will want to tie your attachment to some type of custom or standard object
//n.ParentId = myAccount.Id;
n.Name = 'myImage.jpg';
n.Body = image;
//If we were saving a PDF as an attachment the ContentType would be 'pdf'
n.contentType = 'image/jpeg';
insert n;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to upload file from local server follow this example [Click Here](http://salesforceworld.blogspot.in/2011/06/save-attachment-in-apex.html)

/*****Controler*****/

```
public class status{
private final Applicant__c applicant;
public Blob resume {get; set;}
public String contentType {get; set;}
public String fileName {get; set;}

public status(ApexPages.StandardController stdController) {
this.applicant=(Applicant__c)stdController.getRecord();
}
public PageReference saveApplication() {
  try{
    insert(applicant);                                       
   }catch(System.DMLException e){
  ApexPages.addMessages(e);
   return null;
}

if(resume!=null){
      Attachment attach=new Attachment();
      attach.Body=resume;
      attach.Name=filename;
  attach.ContentType=contentType;
  attach.ParentID=applicant.id;
try {
      insert(attach);
  } catch(System.DMLException e) {
      ApexPages.addMessages(e);
      return null;
  }
  }
  PageReference p = Page.Confirmpage;
        p.setRedirect(true);
        return p;                    
  }
}
```

/*****PAGE*****/

```
<apex:page standardController="Applicant__c" extensions="status">
<apex:form >
<table>
<tr>
<td>Applicant Name </td>
<td><apex:inputField value="{!Applicant__c.Name__c}"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>CV </td>
<td> <apex:inputFile accept="doc, txt, pdf" filename="{!fileName}" contentType="    {!contentType}" filesize="1000" size="50" value="{!resume}"/> </td>
</tr> 
<tr>
<td></td>
<td><apex:commandButton id="submitApplicant" value="Submit" action="    {!saveApplication}"/></td>
</tr>
</table>
</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```